# How to sort two arrays but keep them in a corresponding order?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In my program, I take in a list of grades and a list of names. The order of the grades corresponds to the order of the names. I want to sort the grades lowest to highest or highest to lowest (doesn't matter), but keep it so that the index of person a and person a's grade is the same.

Comment: Don't. Combine the grades and names into a list of your own type e.g., Student.

Answer (score 0):

You can use key-indexed counting sort for this task, the running time of the algorithm is `linear`, I assume that you have at most 2 decimal after floating-point so I am using `Number * 100`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = { "Jack", "Sara", "Smith", "Nour", "Salah" };
        double[] degrees = new double[] { 90.0, 98.6, 98.5, 85.6, 100.0 };
        int N = degrees.length;
        int R = 101 * 100;
        int[] count = new int[R + 1];
        double[] aux = new double[N];
        String[] aux2 = new String[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int pos = (int) (degrees[i] * 100) + 1;
            count[pos]++;
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < R; r++)
            count[r + 1] += count[r];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int pos = (int) (degrees[i] * 100);
            aux[count[pos]] = degrees[i];
            aux2[count[pos]++] = names[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            degrees[i] = aux[i];
            names[i] = aux2[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.print(names[i] + ": ");
            System.out.println(degrees[i]);
        }
    }
```

, output

```
Nour: 85.6
Jack: 90.0
Smith: 98.5
Sara: 98.6
Salah: 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since you're using Java, the natural way to do this would be to create a class, e.g. Student, with grade and name instance members. You'd then have a list of Students that you could sort, which would naturally keep associated data together.

However, if you need to stick with separate lists, the trick is to sort a list of indexes into the grades list, rather than the grades list itself. In the comparator you compare the grades at the corresponding positions in your grades list, rather than the indices.

```
List<String> grades = Arrays.asList("F", "A", "C", "D");
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Tom", "Sue", "Dick", "Harry");

List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<grades.size(); i++) indexes.add(i);

indexes.sort((i1, i2) -> grades.get(i1).compareTo(grades.get(i2)));

for(Integer i : indexes)
    System.out.format("%s : %s%n", names.get(i), grades.get(i));

List<String> sortedGrades = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> sortedNames = new ArrayList<>();
for(Integer i : indexes) 
{
    sortedGrades.add(grades.get(i));
    sortedNames.add(names.get(i));
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println(sortedNames);
System.out.println(sortedGrades);
```

Output:

```
Sue : A
Dick : C
Harry : D
Tom : F

[Sue, Dick, Harry, Tom]
[A, C, D, F]
```

Just for comparison, here's how you might do it using a Student class:

```
class Student
{
    String grade;
    String name;
    public Student(String name, String grade)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;

    }
}
```

Test:

```
List<String> grades = Arrays.asList("F", "A", "C", "D");
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Tom", "Sue", "Dick", "Harry");

List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<grades.size(); i++) 
    students.add(new Student(names.get(i), grades.get(i)));

students.sort((s1, s2) -> s1.grade.compareTo(s2.grade));

for(Student s : students)
    System.out.format("%s : %s%n", s.name, s.grade);
```

Output:

```
Sue : A
Dick : C
Harry : D
Tom : F
```

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

It might be a better idea to create an object to represent your Student (which will contain name and grade as attributes) instead of trying to sync the ordering of different arrays.

Considering both your arrays are already in the same order (`grades[0]` match `names[0]` and so on) you will basically need to:

- iterate one of your arrays to create your Students list;
- create a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort your list in ascending order or a [Comparator.reversed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) if you to sort it in descending order;

## Example

**Student.java**

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Student {

    private String name;

    private BigDecimal grade;

    public Student(String name, BigDecimal grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(BigDecimal grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

}
```

**GradeComparator.java**

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class GradeComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student source, Student target) {
        return source.getGrade().compareTo(target.getGrade());
    }

}
```

**Example.java**

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] names = {"John", "Mary", "Paul", "Alex"};

        BigDecimal[] grades = {BigDecimal.valueOf(5), BigDecimal.valueOf(3), BigDecimal.valueOf(8), BigDecimal.valueOf(2)};

        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            studentList.add(new Student(names[i], grades[i])); // make sure arrays have the same size so you don't get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException
        }

        studentList.sort(new GradeComparator()); // list is now sorted in ascending order

        studentList.sort(new GradeComparator().reversed()); // list is now sorted in descending order

    }

}
```